# Python error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

Hi guys i have a piece of code that gets the number of rows in the table and then requests them but I get

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

Comment: Can you add the piece of code to the question ?

Comment: Without having any code or data to go on, it sounds like you're trying to read something with no data in it. It complains about the very first byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your are trying to parse an empty string (or reading from an empty file). The smallest valid JSON strings must still have a top-level array or dictionary, i.e. `[]` or `{}` are the smallest valid JSON strings.

```
import json
json.loads("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```